# Managing two databases with Firebase and React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native

I have general architectural question and I can't find a good and thorough answer. I am using a Firebase as my backend and I need a way to handle dev and production database.

1. Do you use the same project for development data and production data or separate projects?
2. If later, how do you trigger usage of dev vs production project/database?

Since it's a .plist there is no way of telling "hey use this .plist for this and that .plist for another thing". I hope I explained my problem. Please, share and help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use different projects for development and production. In order to separate these, you could use NODE_ENV. Set it to development or production and in your code check if it is either of them and choose your firebaserc and other firebase config files depending on that. I think that's how it could be done.

Comment: So I would have 2 .plists but how to specify which one to use? Maybe renaming files? That seems hacky. Can you explain it in more depth?

Comment: Lets say u have 2 firebase projects set up. You could add different projects by using firebase add. This will update the firebaserc file to have multiple environments. Looked up at firebase blog and this is what i got.. hope it helps. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/deploy-to-multiple-environments-with.html?m=1

Comment: Amazing. They should make this blog post more prominent. Thanks.